# Preview image replacing images located in other list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two lists within a `<ul>` and each contains a main image along with a container that houses other smaller preview images that take the place of the main image once clicked. It works almost perfectly fine except one thing:

Since I have two main lists `<li>` within a `<UL>`, the images on one list replace the ones on the second `<li>`.

Why is this happening?

```js
function exp(el){
  el.classList.toggle('on');
}


var mainImage = $(".mainimg");
$(".preview img").click(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(".mainimg").attr("src",src);

});
```

```css
/*Main list*/
#list ul{width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:0px;  list-style-type:none; margin:5% 0% 0% 0%; overflow:hidden; padding:0% 0% 4% 0%; }
#list li{border-radius:10px; border:1px solid black; color:black; background:white;  width:100%; height:auto; display:block; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-size:0.9vw; margin:0% 0% 5% 0%; overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-all; word-break:break-word; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; text-align:center; line-height:1.2; }

/* main image */
#list .mainimg{width:20vw; height:auto; border:2px solid black; float:left; margin:1% 0% 0% 1%; overflow:hidden; border-radius:10px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); padding:0%; transition:0.2s ease-in-out;}
#list .open.on ~ .mainimg{width:70vw; height:auto;  float:left; margin:1% 0% 0% 0%; overflow:hidden; border-radius:0px; background:rgba(30,30,30,1); padding:2% 15% 2% 15%;; transition:0.3s ease-in-out;}



/*images expanded */
#list .imgxp{
width:100%; height:0px; background:rgba(0,0,0,1); margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; overflow:auto; }
#list .xp.on ~ .imgxp{
  width:100%; height:auto; margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; padding:0% 0% 3% 0%;}

/*image expander button*/
#list button{background:rgba(0,0,0,1); color:white; width:20%; height:auto; padding:0.5% 1% 0.5% 1%; margin:0% 60% 0% 1.2%; float:left; border-radius:10px; overflow:hidden; }


/*Preview gallery*/
#list .preview{width:7vw; height:5.5vw; float:left; margin:3% 3.5% 4% 3.2%;  }
#list .preview img{width:10vw; height:8.5vw; float:left; opacity:0.7; transition:0.2s; border-radius:10px; border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
#list video{width:60vw; height:40vw; float:left; border-radius:10px; position:relative; top:5vw; left:20vw; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); margin:5% 20% 5% 0%;}
#list .preview img:hover{opacity:1;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id = "list">
<li>
<img class='mainimg' src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/06/16/30/mushroom-3587888_960_720.jpg" /> <button class="xp" onclick="exp(this)">See more</button>


<div class="imgxp">
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/06/16/30/mushroom-3587888_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/03/12/05/tree-99852_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/28/10/36/road-220058_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/01/00/21/bridge-19513_960_720.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<img class='mainimg' src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/28/10/03/autumn-219972_960_720.jpg" /> <button class="xp" onclick="exp(this)"> See more</button>


<div class="imgxp">
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/28/10/03/autumn-219972_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/green-1072828_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/24/15/41/dog-647528_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/19/17/39/starry-night-1149815_960_720.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are two lists with the same class ie. mainimg, you have to specify the src of target div.
Using jquery you can loop through the div of the onclick event

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children(':first-child').attr("src",src);
```

```js
function exp(el){
  el.classList.toggle('on');
}


var mainImage = $(".mainimg");

$(".preview img").click(function(){

   var src = $(this).attr("src");
   $(this).parent().parent().parent().children(':first-child').attr("src",src);

});
```

```css
/*Main list*/
#list ul{width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:0px;  list-style-type:none; margin:5% 0% 0% 0%; overflow:hidden; padding:0% 0% 4% 0%; }
#list li{border-radius:10px; border:1px solid black; color:black; background:white;  width:100%; height:auto; display:block; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-size:0.9vw; margin:0% 0% 5% 0%; overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-all; word-break:break-word; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; text-align:center; line-height:1.2; }

/* main image */
#list .mainimg{width:20vw; height:auto; border:2px solid black; float:left; margin:1% 0% 0% 1%; overflow:hidden; border-radius:10px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); padding:0%; transition:0.2s ease-in-out;}
#list .open.on ~ .mainimg{width:70vw; height:auto;  float:left; margin:1% 0% 0% 0%; overflow:hidden; border-radius:0px; background:rgba(30,30,30,1); padding:2% 15% 2% 15%;; transition:0.3s ease-in-out;}



/*images expanded */
#list .imgxp{
width:100%; height:0px; background:rgba(0,0,0,1); margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; overflow:auto; }
#list .xp.on ~ .imgxp{
  width:100%; height:auto; margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; padding:0% 0% 3% 0%;}

/*image expander button*/
#list button{background:rgba(0,0,0,1); color:white; width:20%; height:auto; padding:0.5% 1% 0.5% 1%; margin:0% 60% 0% 1.2%; float:left; border-radius:10px; overflow:hidden; }


/*Preview gallery*/
#list .preview{width:7vw; height:5.5vw; float:left; margin:3% 3.5% 4% 3.2%;  }
#list .preview img{width:10vw; height:8.5vw; float:left; opacity:0.7; transition:0.2s; border-radius:10px; border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
#list video{width:60vw; height:40vw; float:left; border-radius:10px; position:relative; top:5vw; left:20vw; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); margin:5% 20% 5% 0%;}
#list .preview img:hover{opacity:1;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id = "list">
<li>
<img class='mainimg' src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/06/16/30/mushroom-3587888_960_720.jpg" /> <button class="xp" onclick="exp(this)">See more</button>


<div class="imgxp">
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/06/16/30/mushroom-3587888_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/03/12/05/tree-99852_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/28/10/36/road-220058_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/01/00/21/bridge-19513_960_720.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<img class='mainimg' src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/28/10/03/autumn-219972_960_720.jpg" /> <button class="xp" onclick="exp(this)"> See more</button>


<div class="imgxp">
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/28/10/03/autumn-219972_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/green-1072828_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/24/15/41/dog-647528_960_720.jpg"/></div>
<div class="preview"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/19/17/39/starry-night-1149815_960_720.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should find the main image in a manner relative to the click, or you end up selecting all instances of `.mainimg` on your page. In this case `.parent` will be the `li` tag.

```
$(this).parent().find(".mainimg").attr("src",src);
```